# Hide columns kipping data

Tags: html-table

My problem is the next:
I have a table in which I store information, by clicking on a row there will be a window in which I show that information in a certain format.
The problem I have when I try to make the table responsive because when trying to see it on small devices I have to do side scroll. I tried to hide columns with "display: hidden" but the data I can not retrieve, beacuse it not exists.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor - do not reinvent the wheel and use a specialized library, for example [Datatables](https://datatables.net/). At the very least, take a look at how datatables makes the table [responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/).

You have not mentioned it, so I assume you are ok using jQuery, Bootstrap 3 or 4, Semantic UI or Foundation. For React / Angular there maybe other options.